# value of html input tag type=color is not getting set via JavaScript in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

For setting color value on [this color picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM1vH.png)   in my selenium automation code i am using JavaScript . but it not working
i am accessing the element document.getelemntByclassnname("myclass").value='#00ff00'. it successfully change the value of selected color in the color picker. But when i click the save button , the value doesn't change. The color picker is back to its default value. what else I need to make the value persist .

Comment: Can you share the HTML of the color picker in question? And just as a wild guess, maybe the individual RGB inputs have to be changed?

Comment: Looks like you will need to enter the RGB values into the boxes before clicking save.